# Missing module docstring Pylint (C0114:missing-module-docstring)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I typed in this code and keep getting this squiggly line under various keywords in my source code in the Visual Studio Code environment. Here's a picture...

[image: Image of problem]

I need to understand what this squiggly line is telling me. I need to know why. And, I need to get it to stop. The code does run even with the problem, but I don't understand the nature of this feature.

Comment: if you don't want linting for Python disable Pylint extension, you can also disable individual linting rules, see setting GUI and locate extension Pylint

Comment: What is Pylint for exactly? It was recommended to me by an instructor of mine. I'm just not sure if I really need it or not...

Comment: it finds common causes of problems by static analysis of the code, not all of the rules searched for are useful, you can individually switch them off, if you just write a simple script you don't need a module doc string, why not perform a web search for `module doc string` to see what it is

Answer (score 0):

`pylint` provides detailed code inspection following strict code specifications. It will help you write code that is more spec-compliant. Of course, there are a lot of error messages it provides that don't affect the actual operation of the code, just tell you what the code is missing or where it doesn't conform to the specification. As shown in your question, pylint is telling you that the docstring is missing here, but that doesn't prevent you from running your code.

*More information on **linting** can be found at this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).*

You can turn off **linting** in the following ways.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Enable/Disable linting`

  [image]

The linter can also be toggled in the following ways (`pylint` is one of them).

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Linter` --> choose one linter

  [image]

  [image]

You can also add the following configuration directly in **settings.json** to disable **linting**.

```json
    "python.linting.enabled": false
```

Some warnings can also be ignored by configuring the following parameters

```json
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0114",
        "--disable=W,E"
    ]
```